# AWS EC2 instance with private IP - login without private key using Putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

is it possible login to AWS EC2 instance using PUTTY without any private key file uploaded in PUTTY.

If yes, how this is working? what we have to do for making this working.

Also it does not created public_dns_name, so now how to login to EC2 instance using Putty with ppk file.

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: what os are you running?

Comment: I am trying to login from Windows using Putty. The instance i created is Linux AMI

Comment: By default, you need the private key ( pem) file to login. ( For putty, you need to generate the ppk file). After you logged in, you are able to create users, allow password based login to SSH. ( You may do it for example if you need an SFTP server.)

Comment: ok got it.. Thanks @AdamOcsvari .. also i would like to know first time when i login what is the default user name? is it ec2-user? also if i have only private ip i can use that instead of public dns name.. right?

Comment: The user name varies based on what AMI (Image) are you launching. ec2-user, root, ubuntu are common default user names. If you don't have a public IP, your instance has no access to and from the internet. If one of your instance is private ( has only private IP, is in a private subnet) then you can SSH into an instance in your VPC or set up an OpenVPN tunnel to your VPC. If you are already in your VPC where is your target instance, then you can access it via the private IP.